# 3 nested divs - Fixed Width parent, Left & Right Width based on content, empty Centre Width equaling the difference?

Tags: css, html, fluid

This might be really tricky!

Here is what i want to achieve:

[image: 3 column finella]

Here is my [test code](http://jsfiddle.net/SMNVx/) on jsfiddle

I've tried various things without any luck.
The problem is that both the left and right div widths are based on the text width within. I also cant have the joining dotted line going beneath the lef and right divs and just mask it by background colour as the background of the site is a gradient.

At least in this case, the parent div is fixed though.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is what you really want tab leaders?

Comment: Yes thats what you call them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really hate offering suggestions on using tables but, This would be the easiest way to do it with a table/div/css hybrid solution. Tested and works.

```
<div style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: auto;">
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="float: left; width: auto">
        a
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">
        <div style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff; height:10px;"> </div>
    </td>
    <td style="float:right">
        z
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div style="position: relative; width: 300px; height: auto;">
<table style="width: 100%">
  <tr>
    <td style="float: left; width: auto">
        1
    </td>
    <td style="width: 100%; text-align: left;">
        <div style="width: 100%; border-bottom: 1px dotted #fff; height:10px;"> </div>
    </td>
    <td style="float:right">
        infinity
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: well thats works! But i'm wondering if there is a css display: declaration that is the same as td (table data)?

Comment: I have not tested but, maybe display : table-cell

Comment: PS - you need to put the TDs into TRs i order to validate.

Answer (score 0):

After playing around with the jsfiddle code a little, and looking up 3-column CSS flexible layouts, I tried googling for 'css table of contents'. The first entry was [CSS Table of Contents](http://thepcspy.com/read/css_table_of_contents/), which looks like it might work for you. Otherwise, look at the post being referred to in the post, or at other search results.

Comment: Hmm the thing is it masks the underline with a background, I can't do that with my layout :-/